# For ReactJS, how is the change from using Container components and Presentation components to using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the past, in ReactJS, one way was to divide our components into Container components and Presentational components, and even [Dan Abramov
 wrote a note about it not any more the case](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) if we can use Hooks now.

How should it be done now — how does Hooks solve the problem?

The question is more like: even with function components that can have states, should we still design our app to have container components that have states, and have presentational components that strictly do not have state, and therefore is like "pure function" to take props and present data. *Or* should we not care and use states in every component we have?

Answer (score 0):

With hooks, you can make functional components stateful here is an example

```
Const Component =()=>{
 Const [count, setCount]=useState(0);
 Return(
    <Button

      onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)}      
     >{count}</Button>)}
```

** and if you compare both class-based components and functional components you will see how hooks make it less code and cleaner to read and understand hope I explained well! **

Comment: wait... in the past we can use only class components and they are stateful too... so in the past we can use class components only (and not use function components at all), but in our app we still divide our class components into container and presentational components.  So now functional components can have states, so in our app we don't divide our components into container and presentational components any more? I don't quite get the point

Comment: Nope, you divide your components to containers and presentational components.

Comment: You can do what even a class can make with hooks but cleaner check my edit on the response!

Comment: You are saying today we still divide our components into container and presentational components, but just that we can use function components to be the container, that's all?

Comment: Yes, we divide and use the architecture we want just with more cleaner way and even react team says functional components will have more optimizing in the future means more performance!

Comment: if that's the case, then the statement could have been "use function components as containers" (and still use container components)... I think the statement is more like "don't divide up our containers into container and presentational components any more". (and don't use container components)

Comment: Functional components after hooks can play both roles stateless and stateful personally after working with hooks for months now I don't feel like I wanna use class-based components again as I said functional components are cleaner easy to read and can do whatever a class component can do so I still can use it as a container and also as a presentation components

Comment: so you are saying you would make all components have states now, and won't design your app to have components that strictly do not hold states and is for presentation only

Comment: It's all about your use case! If your component it's only for representing data then why use state! You can use as a stateful or stateless